# Difference Between "Staid" and "Stayed"

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference in meaning between what the following sentences convey?

> Although John was very upset, he approached Jack
>   with a ***staid*** hand.

and

> Although John was very upset, he approached Jack
>   with a ***stayed*** hand.

"[Stayed](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stayed?s=t)" is the past participle of the verb "stay," but you'll see with it that "staid" is, too.  Since past participles can be used as adjectives, it stands to reason that using either or both can be used as an adjective.

"[Staid](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/staid?s=t)," though, is also an adjective on its own, an adjective that may not mean exactly the same thing that the participle of "stay" being used as an adjective would men.  I say "may not" because it seems somewhat different but also seems somewhat the same -- it's close.

Anyway, I'm having a hard time understanding when to use "staid" and when to use "stayed" adjectivally.  Is saying "a stayed hand" even grammatical?  Or, when applying a modifier, are we to use the participle/adjective "staid"? I mean, we can write, "I had stayed," so "stayed" *is* a past participle for sure, but is it to be used as a modifier or is that always "staid"? It seems to me that as a modifier it's usually "staid," but I can't find any data on that.

Also, it kind of seems to me that the first sentence above (i.e., "staid") might indicate a calm hand, John being calm, while the second might not but might indicate that John merely refrained from hitting Jack, which merely keeping yourself from hitting someone can be a far cry from being calm.  But, again, while I've looked, I can't find any data to support that.

***So, when is one to use "stayed" and when is one to "staid" to modify a noun?***

Comment: What did the dictionary say when you looked those two words up?

Comment: It said exactly what I cited above in my research. You suggest that I failed to read the dictionary when in actuality it's you who has failed to read what I wrote.

Comment: By the way, this apparently is an *bona fide* issue, otherwise Grammarist wouldn't have a page dedicated to specifically explaining the differences between "stayed" and "staid," a reference cited in an answer below but one I didn't happen to turn up in my searches, thus this question. (https://grammarist.com/homophones/staid-vs-stayed/ )  That said, that page fails to answer my question, which remains, which if described as such, is it "stayed" or "staid"?

Comment: You're making a mistaken assumption with your thinking that "staid" might indicate a calm hand. "Staid" is a description of long-term character that simply doesn't fit with such an application to a hand in a particular moment. It's like saying he "approached with boring, unlikely-to-change hands"; it just doesn't fit. In the "stayed" example, combining it with the action of the approach suggests the entire time he's approaching, he's mentally or physically restraining his hand from its desire. And yes, one *can* say a "stayed hand", e.g. "Don't misinterpret my stayed hand as weakness."

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/homophones/staid-vs-stayed/), ***staid*** is an adjective and its meaning and usage differs from the homophonic  ***stayed***:

> ***Staid is an adjective that means settled, unadventurous, sedate, steady of character***. Staid is usually employed to signify someone stodgy or dull. The adverb form is staidly, the noun form is staidness. *Staid as an adjectival use of the past participle stayed came about in the 1540s, within a decade it came to mean sober and sedate.*
>
> ***Stayed is the past participle of the verb stay***, meaning to remain in the same place, to reside in a dwelling, often meant temporarily.
>
> - In South Africa and Scotland, stay may mean a place where one lives permanently. Stay can also mean to delay leaving.
>
> The word stay appears in the middle of the fifteenth century, meaning cease going forward, halt, detain, hold back. Stay comes from the Old French estare, meaning to stay or stand, by way of the Latin word stare, meaning to stand, stand still, remain standing, be erect, stand firm, stand firm in battle, be unmovable, linger. Stay with the meaning to reside as a guest for a short period is first recorded in the 1570s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thanks for the link.  I clicked on it and read it in its entirety.  Unfortunately, it fails to address my question about when to use the past participle "stayed" as an adjective and any difference it might inflect as oppose to "staid," which isn't just an adjective but also a past participle of "stay," which it doesn't mention.

Comment: Anyway, I've already given you an upvote.  If you come across anything that answers my specific question, I'd very much appreciate you including it.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - the expression “stayed hand” appears to be really rare, the only similar usage I could find is here https://books.google.it/books?id=1RZHAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&dq=%22stayed+hand%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGuZe_sc7kAhWDCOwKHSwTDt4Q6AEIVjAH#v=onepage&q=%22stayed%20hand%22&f=false, but as this other site suggests https://writingexplained.org/stayed-or-staid-difference- it appears there is not common usage of stayed as an adjective.

Comment: We can say, at least in Britain, that someone should 'stay his hand' (or her hand) to mean 'stop (halt) some course of action that they have started or are about to start". This is a bit old-fashioned, but no archaic. Also, it survives in legal language - a legal action can be stayed (halted). The usage is figurative. No physical hands are involved, thus I begin to think that the OP made the sentences up.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey it's used by Shakespeare, and was less metaphorical when it came to daggers.